# Flutter: Nested navigation inside a page using go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

In my Flutter app, I use [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) to navigate between pages.

Here are the current pages in my app:

- `accounts_page`
- `add_account_page`
- `import_accounts_page`

Now, I would like to implement nested navigation inside `add_account_page`, so I can add a new account using multiple steps, let's say:

- `account_info_step`
- `account_type_step`
- `account_detail_step`

Here is what I tried:

```
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  final _addAccountNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  late final router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
    initialLocation: "/accounts_page",
    routes: [
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _addAccountNavigatorKey,
        builder: (context, state, child) => AddAccountPage(child: child),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            parentNavigatorKey: _addAccountNavigatorKey,
            name: "account_info_step",
            path: "/account_info_step",
            builder: (context, state) => const AccountInfoStep(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            parentNavigatorKey: _addAccountNavigatorKey,
            name: "account_type_step",
            path: "/account_type_step",
            builder: (context, state) => const AccountTypeStep(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            parentNavigatorKey: _addAccountNavigatorKey,
            name: "account_detail_step",
            path: "/account_detail_step",
            builder: (context, state) => const AccountDetailStep(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: "accounts_page",
        path: "/accounts_page",
        pageBuilder: (context, state) => const AccountsPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: "import_accounts_page",
        path: "/import_accounts_page",
        pageBuilder: (context, state) => const ImportAccountsPage(),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

And then I call `context.pushNamed("account_info_step")`, but nothing happens.

Is it possible then to use `go_router` to implement nested navigation inside `add_account_page` and if yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think the way you are trying to create nested navigation is not right. Also you don't need to use ShellRoute, you can use shell route if you want to create something like a persistent bottom navigation bar and changing only the child while keeping the bottom nav bar at the bottom.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:untitled/homepage.dart';
import 'package:untitled/test_page.dart';

final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
// final _addAccountNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyRouter{
  static final router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
    initialLocation: "/accounts_page",
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
          name: "accounts_page",
          path: "/accounts_page",
          builder: (context, state) => const MyHomePage(),
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              name: "account_info_step",
              path: "account_info_step",
              builder: (context, state) => const TestPage(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              name: "account_type_step",
              path: "account_type_step",
              builder: (context, state) => const TestPage(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              name: "account_detail_step",
              path: "account_detail_step",
              builder: (context, state) => const TestPage(),
            ),
          ]
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for. Also, note that you don't need to add a '/' in path for nested screens.
And to navigate to those nested screens, you can do something

---

like this:-

```
context.go('/accounts_page/account_info_step');
```

edit: I've understood your requirement, and I think this will help.
In your code only,

```
GoRoute(
              name: "account_type_step",
              path: "account_type_step",
              builder: (context, state) => const TestPage(),
            ),
```

let’s say you don’t want the bottom nav bar in this screen, there is a parameter called parentNavigatorKey. You can set it with you rootNavigator Key _navigatorKey.

```
GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
          name: "account_type_step",
          path: "account_type_step",
          builder: (context, state) => const TestPage(),  
),
```

Comment: I can confirm, what I was trying to do wasn't right. Thanks for your answer, but my question is: how to wrap the steps in a widget, as you can do with a `ShellRoute`?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm not sure if I follow you correctly. Do you mean creating the GoRoute inside the add_account_page?

Comment: No worries! What I was trying to achieve with `go_router` is to navigate between screens inside a page (like a `PageView`): I have a button at the bottom of my screen, that doesn't move and allows me to go from one step to the next one.
But it feels like it's not possible with `go_router` apparently...

Comment: You mean like the bottom navigation bar that stays persistent and only the screen above changes? If that is what you want, it can be accomplished with ShellRoute, I can help you with it !!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I know I can do that with `ShellRoute`, but I need my bottom navigation bar to be in only one page and not by default in my entire app. That's why I eventually chose to go with the `PageView`.

Comment: Thats also possible, I can help you with that. I have updated my Answer, Maybe that could help you.

Comment: OK thanks! It actually feels a bit weird to "disable" the nav bar for the other pages, but I get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to get to `AccountInfoStep()` full path leading to this builder should be added in your case:

`context.push("/accounts_page/account_info_step")`

I assume you are missing `name` for your top routes to represent proper nesting to use the `context.pushNamed()`

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error: `no routes for location: /accounts_page/account_info_step`. I guess it should be `add_account_page` instead of `accounts_page`, but I don't know how to name the `ShellRoute`, if it's possible...